# How to remove columns of data from a data frame using a vector with a regular expression

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to remove columns from a dataframe using a vector of numbers, with those numbers being just a part of the whole column header. What I'm looking to use is something like the wildcard "*" in unix, so that I can say that I want to remove columns with labels *xxxx*, *xxkx*, etc... To illustrate what I mean, if I have the following data:

```
data_test_read <- read.table("batch_1_8c9.structure-edit.tsv",sep="\t", header=TRUE)
data_test_read[1:5,1:5]
samp pop X12706_10 X14223_16 X14481_7
1 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         4         1        3
2 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         4         1        3
3 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         4         1        3
4 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         4         3        3
5 BayOfIslands_s090.fq   1         4         1        3
```

And I want to take out, for example, columns with headers (X12706_10, X14481_7), the following works

```
data_subs1=subset(data_test_read, select = -c(X12706_10, X14481_7))
data_subs1[1:4,1:4]
samp pop X14223_16 X15213_19
1 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         1         3
2 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         1         3
3 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         1         3
4 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         3         3
```

However, what I need is to be able to identify these columns by only the numbers, so, using (12706,14481). But, if I try this, I get the following

```
data_subs2=subset(data_test_read, select = -c(12706,14481))
data_subs2[1:4,1:4]
samp pop X12706_10 X14223_16
1 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         4         1
2 BayOfIslands_s088.fq   1         4         1
3 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         4         1
4 BayOfIslands_s089.fq   1         4         3
```

This is clearly because I haven't specified anything to do with the "x", or the "_" or what is after the underscore. I've read so many answers on using regular expressions, and I just can't seem to sort it out. Any thoughts, or pointers to what I might turn to would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you can just extract the numbers from the headers

```
# for testing
col_names <- c("X12706_10","X14223_16","X14481_7")
# in practice, use
# col_names <- names(data_test_read)
samples <- gsub("X(\\d+)_.*","\\1",col_names)
```

The find the indexes of the samples you want to drop.

```
samples_to_drop  <- c(12706, 14481)
cols_to_drop <- match(samples_to_drop, samples)
```

Then you can use

```
data_subs2 <- subset(data_test_read, select = -cols_to_drop)
```

to actually get rid of those columns.

Perhaps put this all in a function to make it easier to use

```
sample_subset <- function(x, drop) {
    samples <- gsub("X(\\d+)_.*","\\1", names(x))
    subset(x, select = -match(drop, samples))
}
sample_subset(data_test_read, c(12706, 14481))
```